# How to remove T and Zone from localdatetime in android

Tags: android, localdatetime

Hi in the below code want to remove T and Zone from the LocalDateTime .

Can any one help me with this issue.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
                        firstDayOfQuarteropp = time.with(time.getMonth().firstMonthOfQuarter())
                                .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
                        Log.d("firstDayOfQuarteropp", String.valueOf(firstDayOfQuarteropp));
                        lastDayOfQuarteropp = firstDayOfQuarteropp.plusMonths(2)
                                .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
                        Log.d("lastDayOfQuarteropp", String.valueOf(lastDayOfQuarteropp));
                }
```

Actual output:

```
2020-04-01T11:54:05.514
```

Expected output:

```
2020-04-01 11:54:05
```

Comment: `.514` is the fraction of second (not a time zone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use DateTimeFormatter along with LocalDateTime

```
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now(); 
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formatDateTime = time.format(formatter); 
    Log.d("FormattedTime", "Time: " + formatDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the local date and time.

```
public String formatedDate() {
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return time.format(formatter);
}
```

**And use it as:**

```
String dt=formatedDate();
```